# How to use the virtual keyboard "onboard" with QT5 Application under Ubuntu?

Tags: qt, qt5, virtual-keyboard, ubuntu-15.04

I like to use the virtual keyboard "onboard" with a QT5 Application under Ubuntu 15.04. It has to show up, if -for example- a QLineEdit has the focus.

Qt manual says, that this has to work out of the box, but the problem is that when a QLineEdit-Object gets focused the virtual keyboard shows up and hides directly after that.
The same happens, when a QLineEdit of the QTCreator gets focused. So I conclude, that the problem is somewhere in the interaction of QT5 and the onboard application.

The virtual keyboard works fine with other applications like firefox.
Another keyboard like "florence" works fine with firefox AND my QT5 application.

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked if it's a known bug?

Comment: I did not find a bugreport, which fits exactly to that problem, but something similar: [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46779?filter=-4&jql=text%20~%20%22virtual%20keyboard%22%20ORDER%20BY%20createdDate%20DESC) and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/onboard/+bug/936310).

I found out, that every focused QLineEdit etc. does not stop to send two messages via AT-SPI in an infinite loop:
First messages says something like "I'm focused", second says "focuse lost". So my conclusion is now, that this is a QT 5.5.0 Bug and I will report it.

Comment: Made a [bugreport](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46967)